# Logic App failing to select rows from SQL Server Table with multiple dots in schema name

Tags: sql-server, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard, sql-server-2022

I'm having a logic app that is trying to Get Rows (V2) from On Premise SQL Server. The SQL Server schemna name is having multiple dots in it. The SQL Server table name is [vehicle.small.fourwheel.car.kia].[Picanto], where **[vehicle.small.fourwheel.car.kia]** is the schema name and Picanto is the Table name.

I've tried several things in Azure Logic App, tried passing the table name as a variable, as a parameter, tried selecting it from the drop down list from Get Rows (V2) Table Name list, but every time there is the same error, "The key didn't match any rows in the table.\r\n     inner exception: The key didn't match any rows in the table.\r\nclientRequestId: 28f3f9c4-b5fa-427c-a6f9-b45cdd3d31e1.

If the schema name is just having one dot, then it is working fine.

Need some solution from the experts on this. All of the tables schema names in the database is having multiple dots.

Comment: Assuming that renaming all objects in the database is not an option, perhaps you could generate a set of acceptably-named views to act as aliases to reference the problem schemas and tables. Something like `CREATE VIEW vehicle_small_fourwheel_car_kia.Picanto AS SELECT * FROM [vehicle.small.fourwheel.car.kia].[Picanto]`. This could be done either in the same database or a new database using additional name qualifiers to reference the source database.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, this was working fine for me on premise SQL database. I could able to view all the tables inside the database when connected with the right credentials on Logic Apps without any schema name. Make sure you install on premise data gate way and connect to your on-premise data gateway resource on Azure. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

***RESULTS:***

[image]

***On premise tables***

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's able to view the tables. I was using a SQL Server Action Get Rows, where I was selecting a table, but it was always failing with the error - The key didn't match any rows in the table

Comment: @AritraSarkar Can you make sure your On premise gateway is online and running

Comment: Yes, it's running. When I'm wrapping the table in a Stored Procedure, like the Stored Procedure is having SELECT * FROM Table, then it's working fine. The tables are having multiple dots in the schema name.